# Multithread in Android using ThreadPool

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http, threadpool

I am working with multi threads in android all goes well but i am not able to maintain all thread

- Question 1 : How to get progress of how much tasks has been completed? (scenario below)
- Question 2 : How to group my requests?
- Question 3 : How to make all of my requests synchronous?
- Question 5 : How to keep track all of my threads?

I have shared some code with you guys please help me

**ThreadPool.java**

```
public class ThreadPool {
  private long index = 0;
  private static Hashtable<Long, ThreadPool> list = new Hashtable<Long, ThreadPool>(
        5);

  private ArrayList<Future<?>> futureList = null;

  private String TAG;

  private ThreadPool(int poolSize) {

    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
    futureList = new ArrayList<Future<?>>(30);
    index = System.currentTimeMillis();
    list.put(index, this);

  }

  public static ThreadPool getNewIntance(int poolSize) {
    return new ThreadPool(poolSize);
  }

/**
 * executes a Runnable instance.
 * 
 * @param task
 */
  public Future<?> execute(Runnable task) {

    Future<?> future = null;
    if (executorService != null) {
        future = executorService.submit(task);
        futureList.add(future);
    }
    return future;
  }

}
```

**HttpGetRequest.java**

```
public class HttpGetRequest implements Runnable {
  private final static int TIMEOUT = 10000;

// private static final String TAG = "Http Request";

private String urlstring;
private int action;

private String data;
private HttpCallback cb;
private HashMap<String, String> params = null;

public HttpGetRequest(String url, HashMap<String, String> params,
        int action, HttpCallback cb, String data) {
    this.urlstring = url;
    this.cb = cb;
    this.action = action;
    this.params = params;
    this.data = data;
}
    public void run() {

    String rawResponse = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlstring);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();

        inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                inputStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        rawResponse = sb.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
        try {

            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    cb.onResponse(rawResponse, action, data);
}

}
```

**HttpCallback.java**

```
//interface
public interface HttpCallback {

/**
 * Callback method for http response. called when an http response is
 * received.
 * 
 * @param response
 * @param action
 * @param data
 *            that you want to pass and get it while callback in response
 */
public void onResponse(String response, int action, String data);

}
```

**mainActivity.java**

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
      HttpCallback,  
 {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       HttpGetRequest likesRequest = new HttpGetRequest(
            url, param,ACTION_TYPE_LIKE, httpCallback,
            strData);
       InstaApplication.threadPool.execute(likesRequest);
  }
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response, int action, String data) {

           switch (action) {
           case 1:
              //handle response here 
           break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you brief what you are doing exactly?

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar i am working with instagram API fetching all my images data   comments and like for this i am using thread for faster proceeding bcz my posts are near about 500+ so